# Read multiple JSON files from a folder into a map

Tags: java, stream, jackson, inputstream, objectmapper

For a given folder path, I want to load/transform all the JSON files inside that folder in a single map.

```
InputStream input = new ClassPathResource(jsonFile).getInputStream();
jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input,
    new TypeReference<Map<String, MappedContacts>>() {});
```

I've managed to do it for a single file, but I'm not sure how can I do this efficiently for multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Spring, it was quite easy to use `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` to retrieve all the resources from a folder before using ObjectMapper to transform each one of them into a map :

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(ConfigMapping.class.getClassLoader());

Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/META-INF/resources/mapper/*");

for (Resource resource: resources) {
 InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
 Map < String, MappedContacts> jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, new TypeReference < Map < String, MappedContacts>> () {});
 mapping.putAll(jsonMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonMerge` annotation to tell jackson that your property value should use "merging" approach.

*...In which current value is first accessed (with a getter or field) and then modified
with incoming data, or not: if not, assignment happens without considering current state*

Lets have look at example, 
assume you have 2 (or more) json files:

contacts1.json

```
{
  "person1": {
    "contacts": [1,2]
  },
  "person2": {
    "contacts": []
  }
}
```

and contacts2.json

```
{
  "person1": {
    "contacts": [3,4]
  },
  "person2": {
    "contacts": [100]
  }
}
```

and your `MappedContacts`

```
class MappedContacts {
        @JsonMerge
        List<Integer> contacts;

        public List<Integer> getContacts() {
            return contacts;
        }

        public void setContacts(List<Integer> contacts) {
            this.contacts = contacts;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return contacts.toString();
        }
    }
```

Then to test it works, just simple hello jackson merge :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TypeReference<Map<String, MappedContacts>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, MappedContacts>>() {};
    InputStream input = new ClassPathResource("contacts1.json").getInputStream();
    InputStream input2 = new ClassPathResource("contacts2.json").getInputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Object contacts = mapper.readValue(input, type);
    mapper.readerFor(type)
            .withValueToUpdate(contacts)
            .readValues(input2);

        System.out.println(contacts);
    }
```

Outputs

```
{a=[1, 2, 3, 4], b=[100]}
```